# Store data to be accessed on multiple devices without a server

Tags: html, web-applications

Is it possible to create a client-side only app, with no server backend, that stores data in a way that one user can see things stored by another user on the app?
To give some context, I am trying to create an cross platfor phone application, preferably using html, that will allow users to log their hours in a punch in, punch out style and then have these hours become viewable by a supervisor, however I will not have any server power to store any data.
I'm sure this is possible, perhaps using something like google spreedsheets or something similar to store this data, however I am at a loss how I would do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could possibly use [Google forms](https://apps.google.com/products/forms/). Then you don't need to develop a separate application, you simply collect the submitted data in a spreadsheet.

Comment: You could create a VB.NET (or some other language) desktop app, and place the executable on a network-shared drive for people to use, with data stored in a file. Or, you could use Microsoft Access for forms and database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is "No."
**However** you can use a service such as [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) to host your data for you.